# How can I find the usb devices camera?

Tags: ubuntu, devices, c++, camera, opencv

I am begginer in LINUX, sorry if my question isn't the best.
I have a c++ app that uses OpenCV lib. This app runs at startup via a service(using systemctl). My app needs as arguments, the id of usb camera devices.
I have 2 usb camera. When I switch off these devices, the output of ls /dev/video* is:

```
/dev/video1
```

If I plug in the devices, the output of ls /dev/video* is:

```
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
/dev/video2
```

So,I find out the usb camera devices and right now, I know how to run my c++ app:

```
./my_app 0 2
```

Here is my problem:
My app runs automatically at every start up without to plug in/off my camera devices so I am not able to find out these ids (in this case, 0 and 2).
At each restart, these ids differs.

What is the rules to find out only the usb camera devices?
My OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
My board: Nvidia Jetson Tx2 ( it has an integrated camera that I don't want to use)

EDIT:output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 03f0:094a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 001 Device 039: ID 0ac8:0346 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 038: ID 0ac8:0346 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 037: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The lsusb output may help you.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't help me so much

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Please don't answer @K-att-'s question in a comment. Edit your question and add the lsusb output.

Comment: lsusb -v output then. Hint: https://linoxide.com/linux-lsusb-command-print-usb/

Comment: [Is it OK to add "Solved" to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/355310)

Comment: @zevzek I think you might have missed my point. Fredi didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the easiest solution, using the next command:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

This is the output:

```
vi-output, ov5693 2-0036 (platform:15700000.vi:2):
    /dev/video2

HBV HD CAMERA (usb-3530000.xhci-2.1.2):
    /dev/video0

HBV HD CAMERA (usb-3530000.xhci-2.1.3):
    /dev/video1
```

After that, I made a script to take only the id of usb camera devices:

```
   keywordUSB=usb # used for searching the usb camera
    lineCount=0 # index for each line command
    
    # even lines -> type of camera device : native/usb
    # odd lines -> id of camera
    
    
    USB_ID_CAMERA_ARRAY=() # array where we append our id usb camera
    
    while read cmd_line
    do
        if [ -z "$cmd_line" ] # ignore empty line
        then
            continue
        else
            if [ $(expr $lineCount % 2) -eq "0" ] # usb/native camera 
            then
                if [[ "$cmd_line" == *"$keywordUSB"* ]] # true if it is a usb camera device
                then
                    state=active # state is active only for usb camera devices
                else
                    state=inactive # inactive for native camera
                fi
            else
                if [[ $state == "active" ]] # this is a usb camera
                then
                    camera_id="${cmd_line: -1}" # id camera
                    USB_ID_CAMERA_ARRAY+=($camera_id) # append to our array
                fi
            fi
        fi
        let "lineCount+=1"
    done < <(v4l2-ctl --list-devices)
    
    command="./myCppApp --camera-sources"
    
    for elem in ${USB_ID_CAMERA_ARRAY[@]}
    do
        command="$command $elem"
    done
$command
```